# Elasticsearch multi-word synonyms structure explanation

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, synonym

I work with the synonym_graph feature in ElasticSearch and it seems to work fine.

I was trying to understand, visually, how the new synonym_graph works and splits the words by testing the analyzer directly, using

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "text": "I really love eating lots and lots of fried cheese",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

And I was wondering what the output of the analyzer means.

In this example the term 'fried cheese' has several defined synonyms, some of them are multi-words and some are single words

```
fried cheese => fried cheese, mozzarellasticks, Queso Frito, cheesecurd, friedmozzarella
```

The output of the analyzer is

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "i",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "realli",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "love",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "eat",
      "start_offset" : 14,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "lot",
      "start_offset" : 21,
      "end_offset" : 25,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "lot",
      "start_offset" : 30,
      "end_offset" : 34,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "friedchees",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "fri",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7
    },
    {
      "token" : "mozzarellastick",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "queso",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "cheesecurd",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "friedmozzarella",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "fri",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 43,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "chees",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 8,
      "positionLength" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "frito",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 9,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "chees",
      "start_offset" : 44,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to understand the parameters of the synonym tokens in this result. 
Let's take as an example the synonyms "Queso Frito"

```
{
      "token" : "frito",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 9,
      "positionLength" : 2
    }
{
      "token" : "queso",
      "start_offset" : 38,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7,
      "positionLength" : 2
    }
```

What's the meaning of all the attached parameters? 
"start_offset", "end_offset", "position", "positionLength"

Answer (score 0):

> What's the meaning of all the attached parameters? "start_offset",
>   "end_offset", "position", "positionLength"

`start_offset` is the start of the token i.e. character 38 (`fried` starts at char 38 in the entire sentence)

`end_offset` is the end of the token i.e. character 50 (`cheese` ends at char 50 in the entire sentence)

`position` is the position of the token. Notice how it keeps incrementing from `i` as 0 and so on.

`positionLength` is how many positions the token spans to.

There isn't much documentation. only closest this is found is this from [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.3/painless-analysis-predicate-context.html).

```
token.position (int, read-only)
        The position of the current token
token.positionIncrement (int, read-only)
         The position increment of the current token
token.positionLength (int, read-only)
         The position length of the current token
token.startOffset (int, read-only)
         The start offset of the current token
token.endOffset (int, read-only)
         The end offset of the current token
```

[Some additional reading](https://sease.io/2018/07/combining-synonyms-and-stopwords.html), if you like.